# Using 10 inch TFT touch screen with Raspberry Pi. Does not rotate the touch screen correctly

Tags: raspbian, touchscreen

I am using the lastest version of Raspbian on the Raspberry Pi.  I am using a 10 inch screen TFT touch screen.  In /boot/config.txt, I've added the following 2 lines:

display_rotate=1
xinput set-prop "My Touchscreen driver" --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0 -1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1

These are the coordinates given on a Wiki website: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/InputCoordinateTransformation
and also in another post on Stack Exchange: https://askubuntu.com/questions/368317/rotate-touch-input-with-touchscreen-and-or-touchpad

When I use those coordinates, touching the 0, 0 location, the cursor shows up at the bottom right of the screen.  When touching the top right, the cursor shows up at the bottom left of the screen.  When touching the bottom left, that is the 0,0 location (top left).  Touching the bottom left, puts the cursor at the top right.

The touch screen works correctly in landscape mode, there seems to be no combination that works for when I rotate the screen 90 degrees.

Any suggestions?

Comment: your mouse pointer is 180 degrees from the correct orientation ... doublecheck the transformation matrix

Comment: I've checked the matrix many times and just entered it again. I've tried all of the 3 combinations given, but none of them work.  I've also referenced this site to try to fully understand the maxtrix, but haven't been able to totally understand this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations

Comment: I would really like to fully understand how the matrix works.  What needs to happen is for the x axis to swap values and for the y axis to stay the same.